# issue with moving object in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

here is my code:

```
import turtle as trtl
trtl.hideturtle()
trtl.speed(5)
trtl.tracer(False)
# stop functions
def stopf():
  f.clear()
  f.append("x")
  
def stopb():
  b.clear()
  b.append("x")

def stopd():
  d.clear()
  d.append("x")
  
def stopu():
  u.clear()
  u.append("x")
  
# empty lists for movement
f = ["x"]
b = ["x"]
u = ["x"]
d = ["x"]
# movement functions

def forward():
  for x in f:
    trtl.clear()
    trtl.circle(10)
    trtl.update()
    trtl.penup()
    trtl.forward(0.05)
    trtl.pendown()
    f.append("x")
    
def backward():
  for x in b:
    trtl.clear()
    trtl.circle(10)
    trtl.update()
    trtl.penup()
    trtl.forward(-0.05)
    trtl.pendown()
    b.append("x")
    
def downward():
  for x in d:
    trtl.clear()
    trtl.circle(10)
    trtl.update()
    trtl.penup()
    trtl.setheading(90)
    trtl.forward(-0.05)
    trtl.pendown()
    d.append("x")
    trtl.setheading(0)

def upward():
  for x in u:
    trtl.clear()
    trtl.circle(10)
    trtl.update()
    trtl.penup()
    trtl.setheading(-90)
    trtl.forward(-0.05)
    trtl.pendown()
    u.append("x")
    trtl.setheading(0)

# press and release key tests
trtl.onkeypress(forward, "Right")
trtl.onkeypress(backward, "Left")
trtl.onkeypress(downward, "Down")
trtl.onkeypress(upward, "Up")
trtl.onkey(stopf, "Right")
trtl.onkey(stopb, "Left")
trtl.onkey(stopd, "Down")
trtl.onkey(stopu, "Up")

  


wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

(ignore that im using a way more complicated way to draw a circle than turtle.shape("circle"). )
for whatever reason, when I hold down a direction for too long, it keeps going that direction forever. Does anybody know why this is happening?

It's meant to just move normally in response to the arrow keys, and instead keeps moving after holding it for too long.

Comment: What sort of application are you attempting to build here? There may be a [much more direct way to accomplish whatever you're really trying to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the use of the lists. Let's look at when you press the button to go forward.

**Forward**

The line `trtl.onkeypress(forward, "Right")` calls the function `forward`. For the loop, we see that `f = ["x"]` has been initialized, so the loop begins:

```
for x in f:
    ...
    f.append("x")
```

By adding `"x"` to `f`, you make the loop continue forever.

**Stop Pressing Forward**

Now, `trtl.onkey(stopf, "Right")` calls `stopf`. In turn, `stopf` clears and immediately adds `"x"` to `f`.

This method may work for short periods of time, as clearing the list would stop the loop. However, the reason holding down and releasing the keys undermines the program is that there is a high probability that the addition of the `"x"` in `stopf` would allow the continuation of the forward loop.

This goes for all of the directions. Instead of using a list, you should use a boolean flag to store whether or not a key is pressed.